# Formula to count each occurence of a number in a Google Sheet cells

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, formulas

Having this table;

[image]

I need a formula to be able to find each occurence of the numbers in the range and order them descendingly, like;

[image]

Currently I have this formula but it doesn't work as needed :(

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({A1:F10,LEN(A1:F10)}, "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2 > 0 group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc",0))
```

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of your expected results? do need to sort them descendingly, the numbders themselved? or also their number of occurences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a google spreadsheet, you could try:

```
=query(if({1,1}, ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate(A1:F&char(9)), char(9))))), "select Col1, Count(Col2) group by Col1 order by Count(Col2) desc")
```

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pxWm8X1jwTndsEPLZxjB1QuCWbfwZYckdXR01bs6HOc/edit?usp=sharing) (formula in J1)

Comment: That's an elegant formula! Thanks.. By the way, why did u use `split` and `concatenate`? can I just specify the range directly something like `'sheet_2014'!I2:I54`.. Also, do you how can I rename the result cell header to something other than count? Thanks again :)

Comment: Concatenate() and split() was used to have all the numbers in one column. I'm afraid it won't work otherwise. If you want to rename, you will need to add: ...label Count(Col2) 'your_name_goes_here' at the end (before the ending double quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I came up with a bit complicated and long answer:

here is the screenshot:
[image]

1.a Rearrange the data using **MACRO**

First you need to rearrange your data into a single column, say put them all in column A:
I did this using this macro:

```
Sub convertAllColumnstoONE()
Dim oneColumnHead As Range
Dim columnHeads As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    Set columnHeads = Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With

For Each oneColumnHead In columnHeads
    With oneColumnHead.EntireColumn
        With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
Next oneColumnHead
End Sub
```

1.b Rearrange the data using **formula**
**OR** you can rearrange it into one separate column using this formula, drag and fill down until you get zeros:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,
MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$1),ROWS($A$1:$A$10)),
TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($F$1))/ROWS($A$1:$A$10)),1,1)
```

2. Count and rank

then put this formula in **column H** (drag and fill down till end):

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$1000,A1),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$1000,A1)+(ROW()/1000),""))
```

3. Read and order your data descendingly

with this formula in **column I** (drag and fill down till end):

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNT(H:H),"",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(LARGE(H:H,ROWS($1:1)),H:H,0)))
```

4. Count the frequency

with this formula in **Column J**(drag and fill down till end):

```
=IF(I1="","",COUNTIF($A$1:$A$1000,I1))
```

**Here is the [demo worksheet downloadable](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2sshfhmb89c44pn/list_frequency.xlsx?dl=0)**

***Sheet1*** : *column A is sorted using VBA macro and in* ***sheet2*** *it is sorted using formulas*

tell me if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks @AHCr :) .. a long procedure indeed, I think there might be a better/simpler solution thanks!